# How to config the response time for LongClick?

Tags: android

In Android, [`View.onLongClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) takes about 1 sec to treat it as a long click. How can I configure the response time for a long click?

Comment: It seems that this time is defined by the ROM, not your activity.

Comment: Any idea to work around this issue. I simply want to speedup the response time of onLongClick Listener, btw: I use it for a drag/drop related activity.

Comment: what you want to do in that long click operation ?

Comment: use the long click to trigger the startDrag. but the response time is too long. I want to reduce the response time.

Comment: do you want to drag and drop the listview items ?

Comment: similar like that, It is the for a drag and drop on across some textview. drag and change the positions between textviews. The user doesn't like the 1sec response time.

Comment: I think you have to make a customized view...

Answer (score 10):

The default time out is defined by [`ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getLongPressTimeout%28%29).

You can implement your own long press:

```
boolean mHasPerformedLongPress;
Runnable mPendingCheckForLongPress;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if (!mHasPerformedLongPress) {
                    // This is a tap, so remove the longpress check
                    if (mPendingCheckForLongPress != null) {
                        v.removeCallbacks(mPendingCheckForLongPress);
                    }
                // v.performClick();
            }

            break;
        case  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if( mPendingCheckForLongPress == null) {  
                mPendingCheckForLongPress = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //do your job
                    }
                };
            }


            mHasPerformedLongPress = false;
            v.postDelayed(mPendingCheckForLongPress, ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout());

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final int x = (int) event.getX();
            final int y = (int) event.getY();

            // Be lenient about moving outside of buttons
            int slop = ViewConfiguration.get(v.getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();
            if ((x < 0 - slop) || (x >= v.getWidth() + slop) ||
                (y < 0 - slop) || (y >= v.getHeight() + slop)) {

                if (mPendingCheckForLongPress != null) {
                    v. removeCallbacks(mPendingCheckForLongPress);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I give up on longClick event and using MotionEvent now. Actually, I start like MotionEvent since it was introduce much earlier than longClick (only after API 11). It make my apps easier on more Android phones. I hope Java/Oracle with introduce longClick with simple para as sec/milsec

Comment: "mHasPerformedLongPress" never set true?

Answer (score 1):

This may be late to answer but in case of someone needed.

You can change the time out if your phone is rooted.
simply set the value in database to desired time out value. This will effect system wide long press event.

**directory**: /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases

**file** : settings.db

**table** : secure

**name** : long_press_timeout

By coding ? you may need system app privilege. not so sure actually.
but if you back track the ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() method, you will see that the constant value is coming from Settings.Secure.LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT which is a mapping for **settings.db**

time out set operation is written in View class so it effects every view.